# Mapeando Objetos Json em Flutter

Tags: json, string, flutter

boa noite galera estava estudando mapeamento de objetos json atraves de string. e cheguei a este projeto no flutter.

```
main.dart =>

import 'dart:convert';

class Usuario {
  final int userId;
  final int id;
  final String title;
  final bool completed;

  Usuario({required this.userId, required this.id, required this.title, required this.completed});

  factory Usuario.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json){ 
    return  Usuario(
    userId: json['userId'],
    id: json['id'],
    title: json['title'],
    completed: json['completed']
    );
  }
}



void main() async{

  const String jsonData = """
 [
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "delectus aut autem",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "quis ut nam facilis et officia qui",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "fugiat veniam minus",
    "completed": false
  }
]
""";

  final todos = Usuario.fromJson(jsonDecode(jsonData));

  print(todos[1].title);
}
```

mas ao executar o projeto ele fala que a variavel todos nao esta inicializada
como faço para dar certo e executar todos os dados da string jsonData?

estou seguindo este projeto no site: https://medium.com/flutter-comunidade-br/descomplicando-o-json-em-flutter-47e12b87753b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema que você está tendo é que está tentando converter uma lista de objetos do JSON para uma classe do Flutter.

O que você precisa fazer é percorrer essa lista do JSON e converter cada objeto dela e ir jogando em uma lista.

> Leia com atenção o artigo, que nele mostro certinho como fazer a conversão de uma lista de objetos do JSON para uma lista de classes no flutter.

Em relação ao teu exemplo, veja como ajustar:

```
void main() async{

  const String jsonData = """
     [
      {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 1,
        "title": "delectus aut autem",
        "completed": false
      },
      {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 2,
        "title": "quis ut nam facilis et officia qui",
        "completed": false
      },
      {
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 3,
        "title": "fugiat veniam minus",
        "completed": false
      }
    ]
    """;

  // Transforma o JSON numa lista de Maps que o Flutter entende.
  final listaRaw = jsonDecode(jsonData) as List;
  
  // Transforma a lista de Maps em uma lista do tipo da sua classe Usuario
  final List<Usuario> listaDeTodos = listaRaw.map((item) => Usuario.fromJson(item)).toList();
  
  // Para passar item a item
  for (final element in listaDeTodos) {
    print("Título: " + element.title);
  }
  
  // Para printar um item em específico
    print("\nTítulo do item 1: " + listaDeTodos[1].title);
  
}
```

> Obs.: Fico feliz em saber que meu artigo esteja lhe ajudando nos
> estudos!

#### Explicação

Você estava tentando usar um index para acessar valores de uma classe, que não está correto:

```
  final todos = Usuario.fromJson(jsonDecode(jsonData));

  print(todos[1].title);
```

Como seu JSON retorna uma lista de objetos, primeiro você precisa transformar isso em uma lista de classes, para depois sim conseguir acessar seus itens através de um index.

Comment: Obrigado por me ajudar.. estou tentando agora abrir um arquivo .json e trazer os dados.